# How to scale along a spline Ik rig

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics, splines

I was curious if it was possible to scale this along the spline of a spline IK rig almost like it was growing along the spline.
[image: Spline Ik Rig]

Below is how it scales now but I do not want it to look like this
[image: Not how I want it to scale]
I would like it to stick to the spline and look like the picture below.
[image]

I appreciate any help. It is a little hard to explain with text if you have any question please let me know.

Comment: it's not clear, you say you want it to grow along the spline, so it should be exactly what you show on the first picture and not on the last, no? Also, there must be a problem with your settings because it should not happen like in your second picture. Maybe clarify and share your file?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6715" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6715/)

Comment: Hey thanks for your time. above is a link to the blend file. and for the last image I scaled it down and then ctrl p and automatic weights. so that it looked that way I was wanting. I am also only scaling in the x direction on only the plane.

Comment: oh ok yes it won't work this way, maybe you should find another around like array modifier + curve modifier and you increase the array count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You Change the spline constraint under Y Scale Mode: to "Bone Original"

[image: Scale object along a spline rig]

Thanks for the help!